# World space UI gets blured with Depth Of Field effect when intracting with skybox

Tags: unity-game-engine, post-processing

Im making a game in which players have world spaced UI tags on top of them. but when I use `Depth Of Field` effect and there is no object behind that UI tag (SKYBOX is being rendered behind) the UI gets highly blured for no reason :

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5j4Gr.jpg)

I tried changing the `World Camera` on the name tag's canvas but didn't worked.

I didn't found any solutions for this problems since people don't usually use `Depth Of Field`.

I'm using `Unity Universual Renderer Pipeline` and its `Volume.cs`

Answer (score 0):

This is reasonable, common transparent shaders don't write the depth buffer, so the DOF effect shader cannot know the distance from these HUDs.

To solve this problem, enable write depth feature for these object. Check this example: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@15.0/manual/renderer-features/how-to-custom-effect-render-objects.html

Comment: Hi and tnx. is there any ways I can disable volume effects for this canvases ?

Comment: Assign another camera to the canvas. https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@10.8/manual/camera-stacking.html